# NSCoder fail to decode Float

Tags: swift, decode, nscoder

I have define a class with [String] and Float properties, it's working fine with the encoding process with NSCoder, but it's always fail with decoding.
I have add the guard let into the code, and located it's the problem of the Float $.

I have no idea what's wrong with the Float, I did seen some questions [Fail to decode Int with NSCoder in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072295/fail-to-decode-int-with-nscoder-in-swift) on the web said it's related to optional properties, however it's is not optional variable in my case.

Any advise is appreciated.

```
import UIKit
class aBill : NSObject, NSCoding {
//MARK: - Properties
var payer: [String]
var getter: [String]
var $: Float

struct PropertyKey {
    static let payer = "payer"
    static let getter = "getter"
    static let money = "$"
}

// MARK: - Initialization
init?(payer: [String], getter: [String], $: Float) {
    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.payer = payer
    self.getter = getter
    self.$ = $
    self.currency = currency
    self.remark = itemName

    super.init()

}

//MARK: - NSCoding properties
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(payer, forKey: PropertyKey.payer)
    aCoder.encode(getter, forKey: PropertyKey.getter)
    aCoder.encode($, forKey: PropertyKey.money)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let payer = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.payer) as? [String]
        else {
            print("Unable to decode the payer name for a aBill object.")
            return nil
    }

    guard let getter = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.getter) as? [String]
        else {
            print("Unable to decode the getter name for a aBill object.")
            return nil
    }
    guard let money = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.money) as? Float
        else {
            print("Unable to decode the $ for a aBill object. ")
            return nil
    }

    print("Start convenience init")
    self.init(payer: payer, getter: getter, $: money)
    print("Sucess convenience init")
}

//MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("aBill")}

}
```

Comment: What if you stop using `$` as a variable name? And in particular the encode/decode key?

Comment: In other words, where you have `static let money = "$"` what if you put `static let money = "money"`? Does that help?

Comment: Another idea: could you try defining `$` as Double instead of Float?

Comment: We have think into same way haha, I have try to put money instead of $, but it's the same

Comment: Just try using Double instead of Float, it has no change.

Comment: Sorry, it was just an idea... :(

Comment: Here's another idea: instead of `decodeObject(forKey:) as Float` what if you use `decodeFloat(forKey:)`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124480/nskeyedarchiver-does-not-work-in-swift-3-xcode-8?

Comment: HI matt and Martin R, I just tried use decodeFloat instead of decodeObject, No more error comes out. BUT, it's always decode 0.0 as result, no matter what Float I have encoded(not sure if it's encoded), any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advise,
I have re-try to find and replace all the "$" with "money" in my project, and this time it's was success.

Believe it's because "$" is a key word of file system identifier, so when the project has access to file system, variable $ will have problem.

[image]

Matt, thanks for your advise once again.

Answer (score -1):

u may try
aCoder.encode(<#T##realv: Float##Float#>, forKey: <#T##String#>)
and
aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: <#T##String#>)
because ecodeforkey is for object.